# How to generate platforms with a certain distance between each other

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

Sorry for my english;) I am doing a game using *SpriteKit* with an infinite level (like *Doodle jump*) and I have a problem: I can not understand how to generate a platform so that the new platform is generated at a certain distance from the previous platform.

Here is sample code for generating platforms:

```
- (void)addPlatforms
{
    int random = arc4random() % (int)(self.frame.size.width-80)+100;

    // right end platform
    SKSpriteNode *rightEndPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"leftPlatform"];
    rightEndPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(16, 16);
    rightEndPlatform.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(rightEndPlatform.size.width, rightEndPlatform.size.height - 5)];
    rightEndPlatform.position = CGPointMake(random, 0);

    // left end platform
    SKSpriteNode *leftEndPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rightPlatform"];
    leftEndPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(16, 16);
    leftEndPlatform.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(leftEndPlatform.size.width, leftEndPlatform.size.height - 5)];
    leftEndPlatform.position = CGPointMake(rightEndPlatform.position.x - PLATFORM_RANGE, rightEndPlatform.position.y);

    // left platform
    SKSpriteNode *leftPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"centerPlatform"];
    leftPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(leftEndPlatform.position.x, 16);
    leftPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:leftPlatform.frame.size];
    leftPlatform.position =
    CGPointMake(leftEndPlatform.position.x - leftPlatform.size.width/2,
                leftEndPlatform.position.y);

    // right platform
    SKSpriteNode *rightPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"centerPlatform"];
    rightPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width+rightEndPlatform.position.x, 16);
    rightPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rightPlatform.frame.size];
    rightPlatform.position =
    CGPointMake(rightEndPlatform.position.x + rightPlatform.size.width/2,
                rightEndPlatform.position.y);

    // add to the scene
    [self addChild:rightEndPlatform];
    [self addChild:leftEndPlatform];
    [self addChild:leftPlatform];
    [self addChild:rightPlatform];

    // add platforms to array
    [platformArray addObject:rightEndPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:leftEndPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:leftPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:rightPlatform];

    for (int i = 0; i < [platformArray count]; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [platformArray objectAtIndex:i];
        sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"beforePlayer"];
    }
}
```

Then move it:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [platformArray count]; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *platform = [platformArray objectAtIndex:i];
        platform.position = CGPointMake(platform.position.x, platform.position.y + PLATFORM_SPEED);
        if (platform.position.y > self.frame.size.height+100)
        {
            [platform removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

platforms generated by time interval:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(addPlatforms) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I need to generate platforms with a certain distance between each other (when first platform generated and moved up by 100px - then generating second platform.. etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a variable with information about how "far up" the user have moved. Since your platforms are constantly moving downwards with a fixed tempo simply have a variable _screenAltitude += PLATFORM_SPEED; - then when if(_screenAltitude % distance_between_platforms==0) addPlatForm();

So just to recap: Keep track of your current screen altitude. When that modulus the distance between platforms is zero, then you add a new platform. Just make sure that the platform speed is a clean divisor of the platform distance :) - or the modulus will never be zero.

I would not generate the platforms with a timer :)

Comment: I agree, I would generate the platforms as the characters moves. Timers make your gameplay unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I would try!